# Auto submit when file is submitted - PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to auto-submit the form when the file is selected. I know this question had already been asked on StackOverflow but that didn't solve my problem

```
<form id="img-compressor-form">
<input type="file" class="hide" id="img-upload" name="img-upload" onchange="form.submit()"> // Hidden 
<button name="img-upload-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('img-upload').click();" id="img-upload-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Compress</button>
</form>
```

ajax

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#img-compressor-form").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault()
              var formData = new FormData(this);
                
              $.ajax({
                 url: "assets/script/upload.php", 
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: formData,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                 success: function(data){
                 }
              });

         });
      });
        </script>
```

If I'm not wrong, it is not triggering an ajax call after auto-submit the form.

So what I'm exactly trying to do is trigger the ajax call after auto-submit

What am I doing wrong?

Update:- I tried all of the methods that have been suggested below but none of them worked. everything works fine If I submit the file through the input(file) which I want to keep hidden. It didn't work If I submit the file through the button (which would eventually trigger the input(file) as you can see the onclick event in my code). it didn't do anything after submitting the file through the button.

It worked when I placed this code in the separate js file

```
$('#img-upload').change(function() {
  $('#img-compressor-form').submit();
});
```

Thank you

Comment: use the chnage event `$("#img-compressor-form").on("change", function(e){`

Comment: there seems to be an issue. it worked fine if I submit the file through type='file' but didn't work using button @DeanVanGreunen

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another function in jquery for file 'onchange'.

Rather than
`onchange="form.submit()"` use `onchange="submitForm()"`

and create a function in js like

```
submitForm(){ $("#img-compressor-form").submit(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

as i understand you want to upload file image as soon as it is selected by the input, in that case all you have to do is replace "submit" event with "change".

this will cause the submission to trigger as soon as you add a file.

Example: $("#img-compressor-form").on("change", myFunction());

Comment: Didn't work as I expected. I changed it to the change event but it worked fine only if we submit the file through the input="file" but it is not triggering ajax call if I submit it through button

Answer (score 1):

For your form,

instead of this:

```
<form id="img-compressor-form">
<input type="file" class="hide" id="img-upload" name="img-upload" onchange="form.submit()"> // Hidden 
<button name="img-upload-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('img-upload').click();" id="img-upload-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Compress</button>
</form>
```

try this:

```
<form id="img-compressor-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="hide" id="img-upload" name="img-upload" onchange="document.getElementById('img-compressor-form').submit()"> // Hidden 
<button name="img-upload-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('img-upload').click();" id="img-upload-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Compress</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it worked when I placed this code in separate file  $('#img-upload').change(function() {
  $('#img-compressor-form').submit();
});

Comment: why don't you put it in a separate file then? or in a <script> tag

Comment: Yes, I put the code in a separate file but I'm wondering why it didn't work this way! Any explanation?

Comment: when you try onchange="alert('test')" what do you get?